# Online Photoshop API to change stuff in PSD's

Tags: api, photoshop

A while back - unfortunately I don't know how long ago exactly, but I believe it was somewhere in November - I came across a website where you could upload your PSD and then change stuff in it through the API.

An example: change the text of a specific layer (ie for customized email-headers) or change the background color.

I've searched through Google, my browser history, my RSS reader and email inbox but I can't seem to find it. All I know is that it's an online API, that you have to upload your PSD there and that you can change stuff in the PSD through specifying vars in the URL to the image (the layer-name has to be included). Oh and that it's free.

I thought I added the site to my favorites, but apparently I didn't.

Does this ring any bells for anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Could it be http://www.leichtgewicht.at/272/libspark-psdparser/ or http://pixlr.com/ ?

EDIT: okay, I'm pretty sure its http://daisyapi.com :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It wasn't a website to use Photoshop online, but an API to change your PSD-file (without accessing it yourself through the browser). The article I read about it specifically mentioned the header-image example I previously mentioned (to personalize the image in mailings, so the URL would - for example - be something like: <img src=domain.com/?psd=file.psd&layer3=John Doe (those aren't the actual vars, unfortunately can't remember those correctly either)).

Comment: OMG.. I would say I love you, but I don't think my husband would like that ;-) Unfortunately I can't +1 your answer, because I don't have enough reputation :-(

Comment: @Hiranthi: Dont forget to mark the answer as correct if you feel it is